# Why does the email body show token instead of invite link?

Tags: emails

I have installed and enabled the [invite](https://www.drupal.org/project/invite) module. For mailsystem I have used MIME mail system.

When I send an invitation to email it shows site name and site URL but it did not show inviter name and invite accept link. Instead it shows replace tokens `[invite:inviter:name]` and `[invite:invite-accept-link]`.

While on front end of site, it works fine. But in email body it is not working. See image for more clarity.

Any suggestions?